# making icon run across jframe

Tags: java, swing, icons, actionlistener

```
public class AnimationTester
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
  {
  JFrame frame = new JFrame();

  final ArrayList<CarShape> shape = new ArrayList<> ();
     shape.add(new CarShape(0, 0, CAR_WIDTH));
     shape.add(new CarShape(60, 80, CAR_WIDTH/2));


  final ShapeIcon icon = new ShapeIcon(shape,
     ICON_WIDTH, ICON_HEIGHT);

  final JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
  frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
  frame.add(label);

  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  frame.pack();
  frame.setVisible(true);

  final int DELAY = 10;
  // milliseconds between timer ticks
  Timer t = new Timer(DELAY, new
     ActionListener()
     {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {   
            int x = 0;
            for(CarShape car: shape)
            {
                if (x > ImageObserver.WIDTH) 
                    x = 1;
                else x += 5;

                car.translate(x, 0);
                label.repaint();
            }
        }
     });
  t.start();
   }

   private static final int ICON_WIDTH = 400;
   private static final int ICON_HEIGHT = 100;
   private static final int CAR_WIDTH = 100;
}
```

Hi I'm trying to make a car icon that move across the frame and then reappear on the left side.This code was able to make the car run across the frame, but the icon was not able to reappear on the left side once it reaches end of the frame.I'm posting this code here to get some help while I try to debug along.I think the logical error is here in this block.

```
for(CarShape car: shape)
            {
                if (x == ImageObserver.WIDTH) 
                    x = 0;
                else x += 5;

                car.translate(x, 0);
                label.repaint();
            }
```

here is my current output:
[image]

here the the rest of classes for this program:
`https://pastee.org/k65ev`
`https://pastee.org/668h9`
`https://pastee.org/hxevz`

Comment: There is aspects of your code which are missing which are important in order to provide an reasonable answer. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: sorry about that, i will post the rest of the code via paste bin since it would be too long here

Comment: `i will post the rest of the code via paste bin` - we are not interested in code on paste bin. We want to see a single source file that demonstrates the problem. For example, the actual CarShape is irrelevant to the question. All you care about is that a JLabel will redisplay itself at the left of the screen when it reaches the right side. So all you need to do is create a label with text for your demo code. Once you get the code working then you replace the text with your Icon.

Comment: I think that the icon went of out frame because graphics2d translate method update the coordinate from previous run. Im trying to modfy this method, but im kinda stuck on the logic

Comment: How do i close this post, I solved my own problem